Radar Detection Threshold with Stochastic Echo Energy
I'm currently simulating radar target detection using Linear Frequency Modulation (LFM) signals, and I have a few questions regarding the detection process in the presence of a stochastically modulated echo.
In my setup, the detection is based on the modulus of the received signal after passing it through a matched filter. The noise is modeled as a complex Gaussian distribution, specifically $\mathcal C \mathcal N (0,\sigma^2_n)$. Consequently, the detection threshold can be calculated using the formula:
$V_T=\sqrt{\varepsilon\sigma^2_n\ln{1/P_{fa}}}$,
where $\varepsilon$ is the energy of transmitted signal.
Questions:

In the case where there is a target at the $n th$ range gate, the amplitude of the echo signal is influenced by the target's characteristics (e.g., a Reconfigurable Intelligent Surface (RIS)). This implies that the energy of the echo $\varepsilon$ is stochastic in nature. How should I go about determining the detection threshold in this scenario?
Should I first calculate the expected energy of the echo $\varepsilon$, and then derive $\sigma^2_n$ based on the provided Signal-to-Noise Ratio (SNR) before calculating the detection threshold using the aforementioned formula?
Lastly, what constitutes effective detection in this context? Is it sufficient for the peak of the signal after the matched filter to exceed the threshold, or must the value at the specific $n th$ range gate also surpass the threshold?


Maybe this answer may help: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/95691/26009

Thanks for help!

Let us know if you need additional explanations or if it doesn't capture what you're trying to do.

The post seems to detect target based on CFAR threshold which certainly requires value at the specific nth range gate surpass the threshold. It's actually not the same as my case.

I wasn't expecting it to answer all of your concerns. Sure it's a CFAR detector, but it goes into how one would set a threshold based on a criteria, in this case the probability of false alarm as is your case. To estimate noise and consequently get a detection, you need to sample the values at particular range gates. You say this is not your case...how so?
